# How to disable Comment on facebook post or page

Tags: facebook, comments, disable

I've google searched but couldn't find a working solution. How can I disable users from commenting on my facebook page or post?

Comment: the functionality to disable comments on your posts is not currently available.

Comment: Facebook should have this feature. Not every-time everyone will like people to comment on certain posts

Comment: Yes you can hide certain posts from a person or a group of people. But you cannot disable comments.

Comment: I know I can change the privacy of my post. I just want public to be able to view but not comment on my post